# NodeJs/expressjs : Run lengthy code in a callback

Tags: javascript, multithreading, node.js

Callbacks are asynchronous , So does that mean that if I run a lengthy computation in a callback it wont affect my main thread ?

For example:

```
function compute(req,res){    // this is called in an expressjs route.
    db.collection.find({'key':aString}).toArray(function(err, items) {
        for(var i=0;i<items.length;i++){      // items length may be in thousands.
            // Heavy/lengthy computation here, Which may take 5 seconds.
        }
        res.send("Done");
    });
}
```

So, the call to database is ascnchronous. Does that mean the for loop inside the callback will NOT block the main thread ?

And if it is blocking, How may I perform such things in an async way?

Comment: Callbacks *are in* your main thread - node.js *only has one thread*. Any time you spend more than a couple of milliseconds in node.js without delegating it to another process, you should feel bad. :)

Comment: Yeah, I felt so, But can't anything be done about it? Actually I have exaggerated by saying 5 seconds.  But, Sometimes some processing is required.

Answer (score 1):

For the most part, node.js runs in a single thread. However, node.js allows you to make calls that execute low-level operations (file reads, network requests, etc.) which are handled by separate threads. As such, your database call most likely happens on a separate thread. But, when the database call returns, we return back to the main thread and your code will run in the main thread (blocking it).

The way to get around this is to spin up a new thread. You can use `cluster` to do this. See:

http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html

- Your main program will make the database call
- When the database call finishes, it will call `fork()` and spin up a new thread that runs `your-calculations.js` and sends an event to it with any input data
- `your-calculations.js` will listen for an event and do the necessary processing when it handles the event
- `your-calculations.js` will then send an event back to the main thread when it has finished processing (it can send any output data back)
- If the main thread needs the output data, it can listen for the event that `your-calculations.js` emits

Comment: Looks like a solution, I will have to read first. Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

If you can't do, or don't want to use a thread, you can split up the long computation with setImmediates.  e.g. (writing quickly on my tablet so may be sloppy)

```
function compute(startIndex, max, array, partialResult, callback) {
   var done = false;
   var err = null;
   var stop = startIndex+100;  // or some reasonable amount of calcs...
   if (stop >= max) {
      stop = max;
      done = true;
   }

   // do calc from startIndex to stop, using partialResult as input
   if (done)
      callback(err, result);
   else 
      process.setImmediate ( go look this part up or I'll edit tomorrow)...
       But the idea is you call youself again with start += 100.
}
```

In between every 100 calculations node will have time to process other requests, handle other callbacks, etc.  Of course, if *they trigger* another huge calculation evedntually things will grind to a halt.

Comment: Sure, I will check the process.setImmediate. Thanks.